# Last partition fails to dd copy

Tags: linux, dd

I'm trying to copy the NOOBS Raspbian distribution's 8GB SD card to a new card.

For some reason, the logical partition `/dev/sdb6` will not copy correctly.

Accessing `fdisk /dev/sdb` after the attempted restore gives a couple warnings:

- *"Ignoring extra data in partition table 6"*
- *"Partition table entries are not in order."*

---

Here is the output of `fdisk /dev/sdb ... p` on the source SD card:

`Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           8192  3011718  3003527  1.4G  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2        3014656 15349759 12335104  5.9G 85 Linux extended
/dev/sdb3       15349760 15415295    65536   32M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb5        3022848  3145727   122880   60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb6        3153920 15349759 12195840  5.8G 83 Linux`

My current backup steps are as follows...

`sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=mbr.img bs=512 count=1
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 bs=4M | sudo pv -tpreb /dev/sdb1 > sdb1.img
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb2 bs=4M | sudo pv -tpreb /dev/sdb2 > sdb2.img
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb3 bs=4M | sudo pv -tpreb /dev/sdb3 > sdb3.img
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb5 bs=4M | sudo pv -tpreb /dev/sdb5 > sdb5.img
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb6 bs=4M | sudo pv -tpreb /dev/sdb6 > sdb6.img`

And my restore steps:

`sudo dd if=mbr.img of=/dev/sdb
sudo pv -tpreb sdb1.img | sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdb1
sudo pv -tpreb sdb2.img | sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdb2
sudo pv -tpreb sdb3.img | sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdb3
sudo pv -tpreb sdb5.img | sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdb5
sudo pv -tpreb sdb6.img | sudo dd bs=4M of=/dev/sdb6`

Unfortunately, the image for the logical partition does not seem to copy. Does anyone have any ideas? Here is the output of `fdisk /dev/sdb ... p` in the new/destination SD card:

`Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             8192    3011718    3003527  1.4G  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2          3014656   15349759   12335104  5.9G 85 Linux extended
/dev/sdb3         15349760   15415295      65536   32M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb5          3022848    3145727     122880   60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb6  ?    1221850234 3381616533 2159766300    1T e1 DOS access`

---

sdb1 - recovery OS image, NOOBS boot file and initramfs

sdb2 - any logical partitions

sdb3 - NOOBS settings

sdb5 - Raspbian BOOT files

sdb6 - Raspbian file system

https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/wiki/NOOBS-partitioning-explained

Comment: Why not just copy the entire block device instead of each partition individually?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in your backup and restore steps.

1. The command `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 bs=4M | sudo pv -tpreb /dev/sdb1 > sdb1.img` may or may not do the right thing. I don't have pv to test, but according the manual supplying a file will cause it to copy that file to standard output. Piping content in on stdin and supplying a file to `pv` at the same time isn't specified in the manual.
2. `/dev/sdb2` is an extended partition. It contains the partitions `/dev/sdb5` and `/dev/sdb6`. Your restore steps are copying and restoring the extended partitions twice.
3. The partition mappings are not updated after `sudo dd if=mbr.img of=/dev/sdb`, if a different partition map was there before then it has to be re-read in order for the `/dev/sdbX` block devices to be updated. `sfdisk --re-read /dev/sdb` will do this.

Additionally it's possible that your new SD card has a slightly different number of blocks if it's branded as 8 GB.

Note that the `/dev/sdbX` block devices are merely windows into the `/dev/sdb` block device which represents the whole disk. If you want to copy everything then it would be simpler to copy the block device for the whole SD card instead of each partition individually. E.g `sudo pv -tpreb /dev/sdb > sdb.img` to backup and then `sudo pv -tpreb sdb.img > /dev/sdb` to restore.